# Scroll one single slide with swiper

Tags: swiper.js

I am using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) to try to get one single slide sliding. It's one slide because it has to be a big table by design.

Is it possible to define a width and 'virtual' pages to get swiper to slide this one big 'swiper-slide'?

Comment: Hi, maybe add a mockup/screenshot of your desire result + Add your code (Hard to understand your issue like this). Swiper is for a slider (More than one slide). Overkill. For draggable area - Maybe this trick will be helpful: https://htmldom.dev/drag-to-scroll/. Or for mobile even use simple `overflow-x: hidden`: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

Comment: I try reusing it, because we already use it for other swipes/slides which have multiple divs as slides. This one only has one big table that shoudl slide, so I tried reusing Swiperjs. Maybe I try break up the table into divs before applying Swiperjs 

Comment: Did this work @loremmonkey?  Can you share some code for how you might be getting the big table inside swiper?  I have the same challenge now.